# How to use a variable as an attribute in update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

So I have an object with a set of attributes that are boolean flags that mark whether something has been published or not. There are several different formats it can be published to: published_to_web, published_to_email, published_to_pdf, etc. Rather than having a separate method to reset each format, I thought I would simply use one method, and set the attribute with a variable sent when the pertinent button (web, email, pdf, etc.) was clicked on. So for example a button calls the method and params[:format] = 'web', so I want to set the object's 'publish_to_web' attribute to false:

```
@bulletin.update_attributes( "published_to_#{params[:format]}", false)
```

but I can't get it to work. Seems like  it should be simple in RoR but I can't seem to get the right juju. I've tried:

```
@bulletin.update_attributes( "published_to_#{params[:format]}".to_sym, false )
@bulletin.update_attributes( "published_to_#{params[:format]}", false )
@bulletin.update_attributes( "published_to_#{params[:format]}: false" )
@bulletin.update_attributes( ":published_to_#{params[:format]}" => false)
```

... what's the secret sauce?

Comment: Using `to_sym` on user input is a bomb. I mean, an explosive one. Symbols are not garbage-collected **ever**.

Comment: I started writing an answer and then realized that you almost got it! The last one is 1 character from the solution. Hint: forget about symbols.

Comment: Arrghhh... 95% of the time RoR is brilliant... it's that tricky little thing in haml or erb or whatever that always seem to be a gotcha! Thanks, that did it:

@bulletin.update_attributes( "published_to_#{params[:format]}" => false)

Comment: Yep. Answer your own question then. It's perfectly legit.

Answer (score 3):

```
@bulletin.update_attributes( "published_to_#{params[:format]}" => false)
```

Comment: can you explain what this is doing

Comment: Sure, I have an object model with attributes with the same form:
'published_to_web', 'published_to_pdf', 'published_to_email,' etc. But I don't want to write a different method to reset each one.

On a web page I have several different buttons of the form:

`= link_to reset_publishing_organization_bulletin_path(@organization, @bulletin, type: 'pdf')`

The 'type' parameter is appended as a query string to the URL sent to server, which the 'reset_publishing' method receives as 'params[:type]' Ruby interpolates "published_to_#{params[:type]}" as the attribute 'published_to_pdf' in this case